# How to speed up map display performance?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-desktop, annotation, cache

I was wondering if there is any trick I can use to speed up zooming in/ out or panning through my maps in Arcmap. I usually work on county-wide studies in which I have lots of base layers, imagery and annotation which slow me down very much. I try to keep unnecessary layers off but can't think of anything else. I am using ArcGIS Desktop so I suppose I can not use caches. 
I have not tried it yet but I guess I can use Dice (Data Management) to increase my speed. Any thought/ comment?

Comment: Does any of your rasters have pyramid files associated with them?

Comment: If you don't find that ArcGIS for Desktop meets your display performance then keep an eye out for [**ArcGIS Professional**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66438/what-are-esris-new-arcgis-for-professionals-and-arcgis-professional) which has "a multi-threaded (64 bit) application framework that can take advance of large memory address space and GPU’s for display performance".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should investigate [Basemap Layers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s500000017000000):

> Basemap layers are a kind of map layer that provides a framework onto
>   which you display your dynamic operational information. Basemap
>   display performance is very fast. Since basemap layers are relatively
>   static and do not change frequently, their display can be computed
>   once and reused many times. The first time you visit an area at a
>   particular map scale, basemap layer display is computed. The display
>   is recalled on return visits to that area and map scale.