# Will ArcGIS Pro have (better) ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, arcgis-10.3

An earlier Q&A ([What are Esri's new "ArcGIS for Professionals" and "ArcGIS Pro"?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66438)) provided some reassurance that **ArcPy** code would have re-use value with **ArcGIS Pro**:

> **ArcGIS Professional Extensibility.** Here are our current thoughts about extensibility for ArcGIS Pro. You can write and run Python
>   scripts in ArcGIS that call geoprocessing tools and use an exhaustive
>   suite of scripting functions available in the ArcGIS Python API,
>   ArcPy, to automate your GIS tasks.

However, it makes no mention of whether ArcGIS Pro will enable model building to automate workflows using a GUI that is either (equivalent to) the existing ModelBuilder or a major improvement on it to address [previous enhancement requests](http://polygeo.com.au/2013/06/07/top-10-improvements-id-like-to-see-in-arcgis-10-2-for-desktop-3-modelbuilder-background-geoprocessing-progress-indicator/) from others and I.

Has anyone heard the **road ahead** for ModelBuilder (or at least model building) in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, ArcGIS Professional will have ModelBuilder. ModelBuilder will be a view like a map or layout. You will be able to run and edit existing models and create new ones using ModelBuilder.